# How to identify what are the exact elements of a vector?

Tags: r, testing, equals, intervals, or-condition

I have a vector `x` of the form:

```
x=c(601, 602, 603, 604, 605, 606, 607, 608, 609, 610, 611, 612, 613, 614,
 615, 616, 617, 618, 619, 620, 621, 622, 623, 624, 625, 626, 627, 628, 629, 630,
 631, 632, 633, 634, 635, 636, 637, 638, 639, 640, 641, 642, 643, 644, 645, 646,
 647, 648, 649, 650)
```

If `length (x) == 50`: I would like to test (**TRUE** or **FALSE**) if **x is exactly equal to one of the intervals 1:50 or 51:100 or 101:150 or 151:200 .... or 951:1000**.

Or if `length (x)> 50`, I would like to test (**TRUE** or **FALSE**) if **x is exactly equal to the union of intervals composed by ((1:50 U 51: 100) or (1:50 U 101: 150) or (51 : 100 U 151: 200) ....)**.

My attempt:

```
all(
    x == c(1:50) | 
    x == c(51:100) | 
    x == c(101:150) | 
    x == c(151:200) | 
    x == c(201:250) | 
    x == c(251:300) | 
    x == c(301:350) | 
    x == c(351:400) | 
    x == c(401:450) | 
    x == c(451:500) | 
    x == c(501:550) | 
    x == c(551:600) | 
    x == c(601:650) | 
    x == c(651:700) | 
    x == c(701:750) | 
    x == c(751:800) | 
    x == c(801:850) | 
    x == c(851:900) | 
    x == c(901:950) | 
    x == c(951:1000)
)
```

I would like to optimize this code.

PS: I'm not trying to have a frequency table of the `x` elements and intervals like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839432/how-to-generate-bin-frequency-table-in-r). I want to know if `x` corresponds exactly to one or the union of those intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a `data.table` solution:

```
test <- function(u){
  ifelse(all(as.data.table(u)[, 
                              .N, 
                               by = cut(u, 
                                        breaks = seq(0, 1000, 50))][, unique(N)] == 50), 
         TRUE, 
         FALSE)
}
```

### Tests:

```
x <- 1:50 # TRUE
y <- 2:51 # FALSE
z <- 1:100 # TRUE
w <- 2:101 # FALSE

test(x)
> TRUE

test(y)
> FALSE

test(z)
> TRUE

test(w)
> FALSE
```

Comment: you need to `library(data.table)` before defining the function

Answer (score 4):

You can use `cut`, i.e.

```
unique(cut(x, breaks = seq(0, 1000, by = 50)))
#[1] (600,650]
```

If you want a boolean If `x` is included in one those intervals, then you can do,

```
unique(cut(x, breaks = seq(0, 1000, by = 50))) != ''
#[1] TRUE

#or If you only want to be in 1 group, then as suggested by Ronak,
length(unique(cut(x, breaks = seq(0, 1000, by = 50)))) == 1
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @RonakShah right...I thought they wanted which interval...I ll edit

Comment: This code does not work if x = c (1: 103), it gives TRUE whereas (1: 103) is not exactly equal to one of the intervals 1:50 or 51: 100 or 101: 150 nor to the union (1:50) u (51: 100)....

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
test <- function(x) length(x)%%50==0 & x[length(x)]%%50==0 & all(diff(x)==1)
```

`length(x)%%50==0` ensures that the vector is of length that are multiples of 50.

`x[length(x)]%%50==0` checks that the last element is divisible by 50.

`all(diff(x)==1)` checks that vector is a sequence in steps of 1. (e.g. `x <- rep(50,50)` will fail this part)

check:

```
> test(1:50)
#[1] TRUE
> test(2:51)
#[1] FALSE
> test(1:100)
#[1] TRUE
> test(2:101)
#[1] FALSE
```